# How can i open main activity after target activity launched by notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I have two activities.`MessageActivity` and `MainActivity`. When user clicks on notification, the `MessageActivity` will be launched.
I want to launch `MainActivity` after finishing `MessageActivity` if app was closed and
Whenever app is running, just finish `MessageActivity`.

Here is my code,
I use oneSignal notification and do not create notification by my Own.

```
 @Override
 public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
     OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
     JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

     Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.getContext(), 
     MessageActivity.class);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     MyApplication.getContext().startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: Add the activity to the backstack while handling the intent.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Let me know if I was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. Because I used from OneSignal, I could not use  Anindya Dutta approach. Your solution was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After click a notification and launch MesageActivity, you can also send a flag in your putExtra like this

```
intent.putExtra("OpenActivityFromNotification", true);
```

In your MesageActivity after OnCreate you can get the value:

```
boolean isActivityOpenedFromNotification =  intent.getBooleanExtra("OpenActivityFromNotification", false);
```

Then, in your MesageActivity you can onverride OnBackPressed with something lik this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isActivityOpenedFromNotification){
         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 
             MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Nice coding!

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish();` inside your MessageActivity whenever you want to close it and get back to the caller activity (MainActivity in your case).

Comment: You would need to add the MainActivity to the task first.